# Why did suppressing warning 8600 become "Unnecessary" in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, suppress-warnings, .net-5

When I built my C# application with .NET Core 3.1 at warning level 5, I had to either fix or manually suppress warning 8600 in this code or my application would not build.  For example:

```
#pragma warning disable 8600 // string literal.  
throw new ExternalException("Invalid path", result);
#pragma warning restore 8600
```

The warning was that I was using a string literal in the exception.  That makes sense;  The string might become user-facing so it should be in a RESX file.  This helped me track down all of the hard-coded UI strings in my app and so made our translation efforts more reliable

But now that I have upgraded to .NET 5/C#9, the Visual Studio 2019 Error window (version 16.8.3)  tells me "Remove Unnecessary Suppression" for the bit of code above.  My code builds fine without it.

Why would this warning now be unnecessary?

(This doesn't have anything to do with CodeAnalyzer NuGet packages does it?)

Comment: That is [documented](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/16944), no real idea what they are actually trying to say.  The only whiff I get is that too many people got that warning, so they removed it.

Comment: Well that's a shame.  I can't understand why people didn't just disable it.  I see the same issue with former FxCop warning CA1303 which is roughly the same thing.  Now that I've moved from the FxCop analyzers to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers (as the very build process instructed me to once I moved to .NET 5), that warning also is considered "unnecessary".  I find it quite necessary.

Comment: And thank you again.   I must admit, even after looking at the issue you linked to, without your analysis of it, the reason it was removed would be completely unclear.    Sure, I see the issue and I see it was closed.  But I follow all the links there that I can but still I do not see why